# toggle neovim terminal buffer like nerdtree plugin

Tags: vim-plugin, nerdtree, neovim

since we have the option to have a terminal inside a neovim buffer. I would very much like to have a way to "toggle" the buffer containing the terminal and have it appear in a fixed position like say the bottom of the screen.

I know that nerdtree does this for me, it toggles with a keybinding to always appear on my left side of the screen. what i wish for is the same with the terminal buffer in neovim. Is there anyone who knows of a plugin like this or how i would create one?

Answer (score 7):

That's my solution to anyone who wanna hide/show a single neovim terminal window of any height.

The terminal will show at very bottom in insert mode. If you wanna change the split behaviour just edit `botright new` to something else. `:help opening-window`

```
let g:term_buf = 0
let g:term_win = 0

function! Term_toggle(height)
    if win_gotoid(g:term_win)
        hide
    else
        botright new
        exec "resize " . a:height
        try
            exec "buffer " . g:term_buf
        catch
            call termopen($SHELL, {"detach": 0})
            let g:term_buf = bufnr("")
        endtry
        startinsert!
        let g:term_win = win_getid()
    endif
endfunction


nnoremap <M-t> :call Term_toggle(10)<cr>
tnoremap <M-t> <C-\><C-n>:call Term_toggle(10)<cr>
```

Answer (score 3):

I might have a solution for you. The code below toggles a terminal on the far left with the f4-button:

```
let g:term_buf = 0
function! Term_toggle()
  1wincmd w
  if g:term_buf == bufnr("")
    setlocal bufhidden=hide
    close
  else
    topleft vnew
    try
      exec "buffer ".g:term_buf
    catch
      call termopen("bash", {"detach": 0})
      let g:term_buf = bufnr("")
    endtry
    startinsert!
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <f4> :call Term_toggle()<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually works somewhat! i am trying to get it to start work for the bottom, but it refuses to toggle, it jus opens a new buffer window instead.

i changed the line: 'topleft vnew' to 'botright new' any ideas?

Comment: The command also adds a lot of [No name] buffers

Comment: I am not very familiar with remote windows, but I would think that you could use `windo` here. Send a command to all windows, and save `winnr()` for the window that are terminal buffers to a global variable. Then switch to that window and do the stuff from my function.

Comment: As for the `[no name]`, I'm not sure what is going on. If the `exec` term fails every time it is run, then obviously it will respawn and hide a lot of buffers, but I thought the code dealt with that.

Is your terminal the same one on each toggle, or do you get a new spawn?

Comment: No i checked that, the exec succeds everytime. Also i changed the 'call termopen...' to 'terminal' gives the same results. 

The terminal is the same even thought it creates a lot of [no name]-buffers. I tried to modify it so instead of 1wincmd i would use '"sbuffer"g:term_buf", but that didnt work

Comment: I'm not getting that behavior on my side, and I'm not sure what it could be. Hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I Think this must be a little better more IDE Like,

```
let g:term_buf = 0
function! Term_toggle()
  1wincmd w
  if g:term_buf == bufnr("")
    setlocal bufhidden=hide
    close
  else
    rightbelow new
    12winc -
    try
      exec "buffer ".g:term_buf
    catch
      call termopen("bash", {"detach": 0})
      let g:term_buf = bufnr("")
    endtry
    set laststatus=0
    startinsert!
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <f4> :call Term_toggle()<cr>

" Terminal go back to normal mode
tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>
" When switching to terminal windows it goes into insert mode automatically
au BufEnter * if &buftype == 'terminal' | :startinsert | endif
```

Comment: I like this better, however it still generates a lot of these empty buffers as well.

Answer (score 1):

An simple solution, but it deletes the buffer:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F3> :split term://zsh <CR>
tnoreamp <silent> <F3> <C-\><C-n> :bd! <CR>
autocmd TermOpen * startinsert
```

the terminal buffer needs to be selected to be closed!